# how to clear okta user token

Tags: reset, okta, multi-factor-authentication

Our site uses okta for authentication. The user goes to the login page and enters their username & password. Then it uses the /api/v1/authn endpoint to authenticate them. If okta returns "MFA_REQUIRED" it sends them to the page where they enter their MFA code. All this is working fine.

The problem I have is sometimes I need to test the login process described above with a test user and force it to use the "MFA_REQUIRED" state. If the user has recently logged in,  it will just return "SUCCESS".

I tried going into the okta admin control panel to clear the token by clicking on "Clear User Sessions" here:

[image]

Clicking that shows this:

[image]

However, if I then try to login with the test user after clearing the session, it still returns "SUCCESS". I don't want to go through the entire enrollment process, just to reset the token. How can I clear out the token to force the MFA_REQUIRED state?

Answer (score 0):

Until the token stored in the specified token storage will have its accessToken still valid and not expired, you will always receive SUCCESS.
You could mitigate this behaviour by minimizing the accessToken lifetime to the lower bound (5 minutes).